# SQL Give fields a single name when there are multiple variances with numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like so.

```
ID   Name        Year
404  Matt        2015
406  Matt 1      2015
304  Matt 2      2015
334  Matt3       2015
655  Matt4       2015
923  Matt 5      2015
856  Banana      2015
274  Banana 2    2015
716  Banana7     2015
472  Orangutan   2015
844  OrangutanA 2015
159  Orangutan 2 2015
739  Big Foot    2015
866  Big Foot B  2015
273  Big Foot 5  2015
896  Big FootB   2015
```

And I would like to add an extra column to this table which groups Names (ignoring numbers and letters after them)

If it was just numbers after the name i would just remove numbers however some have letters a, b, c etc and some have letters and numbers!

My expected output would be.

```
ID   Name        Year  SName
404  Matt        2015  Matt
406  Matt 1      2015  Matt
304  Matt 2      2015  Matt
334  Matt3       2015  Matt
655  Matt4       2015  Matt
923  Matt 5      2015  Matt
856  Banana      2015  Banana
274  Banana 2    2015  Banana
716  Banana7     2015  Banana
472  Orangutan   2015  Orangutan
844  OrangutanA  2015  Orangutan
159  Orangutan 2 2015  Orangutan
739  Big Foot    2015  Big Foot
866  Big Foot B  2015  Big Foot
273  Big Foot 5  2015  Big Foot
896  Big FootB   2015  Big Foot
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3e7c7

Input Script:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
    ("ID" int, "Name" varchar2(11), "Year" int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO mytable ("ID", "Name", "Year")
         VALUES (404, 'Matt', 2015)
    INTO mytable ("ID", "Name", "Year")
         VALUES (406, 'Matt 1', 2015)
    INTO mytable ("ID", "Name", "Year")
         VALUES (304, 'Matt 2', 2015)
    INTO mytable ("ID", "Name", "Year")
         VALUES (334, 'Matt3', 2015)
    INTO mytable ("ID", "Name", "Year")
         VALUES (655, 'Matt4', 2015)
    INTO mytable ("ID", "Name", "Year")
         VALUES (923, 'Matt 5', 2015)
    INTO mytable ("ID", "Name", "Year")
         VALUES (856, 'Banana', 2015)
    INTO mytable ("ID", "Name", "Year")
         VALUES (274, 'Banana 2', 2015)
    INTO mytable ("ID", "Name", "Year")
         VALUES (716, 'Banana7', 2015)
    INTO mytable ("ID", "Name", "Year")
         VALUES (472, 'Orangutan', 2015)
    INTO mytable ("ID", "Name", "Year")
         VALUES (844, 'OrangutanA', 2015)
    INTO mytable ("ID", "Name", "Year")
         VALUES (159, 'Orangutan 2', 2015)
    INTO mytable ("ID", "Name", "Year")
         VALUES (739, 'Big Foot', 2015)
    INTO mytable ("ID", "Name", "Year")
         VALUES (866, 'Big Foot B', 2015)
    INTO mytable ("ID", "Name", "Year")
         VALUES (273, 'Big Foot 5', 2015)
    INTO mytable ("ID", "Name", "Year")
         VALUES (896, 'Big FootB', 2015)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

Comment: Could you please provide the create and insert scripts? Or at least a SQL Fiddle with schema built? You could do it easily using **REGEXP_SUBSTR**. You could also do it with old **SUBSTR+INSTR**. I would suggest go for **VIRTUAL COLUMNS**.

Comment: The business rules need clarifying.  How, for example, would you like to handle these names?  `{"Big", "Big a", "Big Foot", "Big Foot a"}` or `{"Mat", "Mat1", "Matt", "Matt1"}`, etc, etc.

Comment: @MatBailie expected output is the bottom table column `SName`

Comment: @LalitKumarB SQL Fiddle and Scripts added to question

Comment: @Matt I removed my answer because you need to explain the rule for `OrangutanA`. `Matt3` could be handled easily by considering only alphabets, however, `OrangutanA` are all alphabets, so how do you explain the rule for this.

Comment: @LalitKumarB ok so for the ones with letters they need their letters removing, they are in the format of `nameA`, `nameB` etc or `name A`, `name B` or some are `nameA`, `name 2`. Expected output shows what the output should be in column `SName`

Comment: @Matt - If you look at my examples carefully, then you will notice that your expected output is ambiguous in those cases.  Should all four of my first examples be `"Big"` or should there be `"Big"` ***and*** `"Big Foot"`, and if so, what business rules do you want to apply to differentiate between the two?  The same applies to `"Mat"` and `"Matt"` being different names.  In short: If one name is a subset of another name, how do you propose disambiguating them?

Comment: @MatBailie I wouldnt say they were ambiguous, if the input was `Big Foot1` and `Big Foot2` then thou outputs would be `Big Foot`, if the inputs were `Big 1` and `Big 2` then the output would be `Big`

Comment: @Matt But what about `MattA`, `Big Foot 1`

Comment: @LalitKumarB they would be `Matt` & `Big Foot` Respectively.

Comment: @Matt: You don't understand what MatBailie is asking. If you have two names 'Big' and 'Big Foot', are these both the name 'Big', i.e. is 'Big Foot then just 'Big' plus some letters attached? If not, why is 'Big A'? And how do you know that 'OrangutanA' is 'Orangutan' plus 'A'? Because the A is a capital letter? So 'Orangutana' would be another name? And 'OrangutanAnn'? Give us a precise rule how to tell the name from the added letters and digits.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner if it has a letter or a single number at the end of it it needs removing i.e. 1 2 3 4 or a b c d

Comment: @Matt: Well then, ... As 'Matt' has a letter 't' in the end, the real name is 'Mat'. That doesn't match your example, however, where you want it to be 'Matt'. So this is cannot be the real rule.

Comment: @Matt - "Big Foot" has a letter at the end, "t", so again is that OK because it isn't a single upper-case letter? Or are you only interested in a-d whatever their case; in which case "Banana" is in trouble? Or are you looking for something which is another shorter entry plus any characters - which could also have edge cases, if you had both "Big" and "Big Foot". It isn't clear how you decide what the 'root' version of each string value should be.

Comment: So is a capital letter at the end of the name the rule to use to find "invalid" letters at the end if names? Because there could be someone named Mata or Matta and those can both be legit names. Technically you can still have capital letters at the end of names too. Examples "JD", " JR", "KC". So your rules still need clarified.

Comment: @Matt - The case of `{"Mat", "Mat1", "Matt", "Matt1"}` still remains non-trivial.   `"Mat"` will cause `"Mat1"` and `"Matt"` to both be `"Mat"` with a single trailing number or letter.  But then what happens to `"Matt1"`?  Is it `"Mat"` with a trailing `"t1"`?  Your comment mentions a ***single*** letter or number, so that can't be possible?  So does it become `"Matt"` with a trailing `"1"`?  That would be weird because `"Matt"` is already `"Mat"` with a trailing `"t"`.  So, does it become it's own unique name?

Comment: And I am afraid that the next rule we'll see will cause problems with 'Henry VIII' and 'George Hamilton IV' ;-)

Comment: I'm guessing the real data this will be applied to isn't actually names, and doesn't have the ambiguities, but we can only work from the example, sadly. - even if it may have sent us down some irrelevant rabbit holes. A clear requirement is still necessary though.

Comment: If the real requirement is known, probably we could use [**UTL_MATCH string comparision technique**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/04/30/utl_match-string-comparision-technique-in-oracle/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If** the rule you're trying to apply is simply that you want to remove a single digit or uppercase character at the end of the value, with or without a single preceding space; and your real data is less ambiguous than speculated in comments and the complications and edge cases really don't apply; then you can use a fairly simple regular expression to remove a pattern:

```
select "ID", "Name", "Year",
  regexp_replace("Name", '[ ]?[[:upper:][:digit:]]$', null) as "SName"
from mytable;

        ID Name              Year SName                                            
---------- ----------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------
       404 Matt              2015 Matt                                              
       406 Matt 1            2015 Matt                                              
       304 Matt 2            2015 Matt                                              
       334 Matt3             2015 Matt                                              
       655 Matt4             2015 Matt                                              
       923 Matt 5            2015 Matt                                              
       856 Banana            2015 Banana                                            
       274 Banana 2          2015 Banana                                            
       716 Banana7           2015 Banana                                            
       472 Orangutan         2015 Orangutan                                         
       844 OrangutanA        2015 Orangutan                                         
       159 Orangutan 2       2015 Orangutan                                         
       739 Big Foot          2015 Big Foot                                          
       866 Big Foot B        2015 Big Foot                                          
       273 Big Foot 5        2015 Big Foot                                          
       896 Big FootB         2015 Big Foot
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3e7c7/3).

Or as @LalitKumarB suggested, use a virtual column:

```
alter table mytable add ("SName" varchar2(11) as
  (cast(regexp_replace("Name", '[ ]?[[:upper:][:digit:]]$', null) as varchar2(11))));
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9ef06/1).

The `cast()` is needed because the string returned by `regexp_replace()` isn't size-constrained - it doesn't necessarily know about the limit on the size of the input value, and you could be making it longer - and could be up to 4000 characters (or 32k in 12c); so the `alter` would get ORA-12899 without it.

These are getting the required result for the sample data you provided, but if your rule is really more complicated and you have more complicated data, then it would need to be amended - or a completely different approach might be needed (recursion, model clause, ... depending on the full requirement).

Comment: `regexp_replace` is the icing on the cake here. I was going around `regexp_substr`. Nice, really nice +1 Wish there was a favorite answer icon or something similar to keep them saved for future ref.

Comment: @LalitKumarB - yes, I'm going to struggle to find this in my own list of answers in the future... maybe having a blog isn't such a bad idea!

Comment: @AlexPoole This will be useful over and over again!

Answer (score 3):

The following query builds triples from the ids of records containing the base and the derived names and the short name (base and derived in terms of prefixes of "Name" values  as defined below).

The Assumptions (and these are restrictive !) are that:

- any pair of derived Names have a common prefix
- that common prefix does not have a common prefix with any other db entry
- there is a db record with the common prefix itself.
- for each base record there is at least 1 derived record.

'prefix' means true prefix.

```
select derived.ID   did
     , base.ID      bid
     , base."Name"  SName
  from mytable base
  join mytable derived on ( INSTR(derived."Name", base."Name" ) = 1 and derived."Name" <> base."Name" )
     ;
```

**Update**

A full-fledged query providing the result set columns the OP asked for and including the base cases follows (the same caveats apply):

```
select derived.ID      OrigID
     , derived."Name"  OrigName
     , base."Name"     SName
     , base."Year"     OrigYear
  from mytable base
  join mytable derived on ( INSTR(derived."Name", base."Name" ) = 1 and derived."Name" <> base."Name" )
union all
select base.ID      OrigID
     , base."Name"  OrigName
     , base."Name"  SName
     , base."Year"  OrigYear
  from mytable base
 where base.ID IN ( select distinct b.ID
                      from mytable b
                      join mytable d on ( INSTR(d."Name", b."Name" ) = 1 and d."Name" <> b."Name" ) )
     ;
```

Comment: But your JOIN condition would leave out few rows. That's not what OP wants.

Comment: @LalitKumarB  The join condition skips precisely over those records which essentially copy the original record, namely those containing the base cases ( Matt, Banana, Orangutan, Big Foot in the sample). It is straightforward to add those cases to the result set.

Comment: Good one, something different +1

Comment: I am thinking [JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY function](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/04/30/utl_match-string-comparision-technique-in-oracle/) would also be handy here.

Answer (score 1):

No doubt, there is a way to do this with `regexp_substr()`, but a `case` seems simple enough:

```
select (case when regexp_like(name, '^.* [0-9A-Z]$')
             then substr(name, 1, length(name) - 2)
             when regexp_like(name, '^.*[0-9A-Z]$')
             then substr(name, 1, length(name) - 1)
             else name
        end) as newname
```

Comment: This gives a `ORA-00920: invalid relational operator` error

Comment: `regexp_like` takes the the value and pattern as two arguments, and doesn't understand %. Seems simpler to do a single `regexp_replace` than two `regexp_like` calls anyway; *if* this is actually the rule that's needed.

Comment: It seems incorrect syntax to me. Are you sure it is for Oracle?

Comment: @Matt . . . It was a weird hybrid syntax.  I fixed it so it is Oracle-compatible.